# Populate multiple TextViews from an arraylist in android

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I have a firebase backend for my android app. I've pulled the data I need from the backend (Names of different players) and put it in an arraylist of Strings ..For example

```
{"John Doe1", "John Doe2"...."John Doe15"}
```

I now need to populate 15 different textviews Ids with these names for my activity. What is the most efficient way to do this? Here is my code so far and here is what my activity looks like...

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            ArrayList<String> al= new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                Player player = snapshot.getValue(Player.class);

                String name=player.Name;

                al.add(name);


            }
```

[image: textviews in actvity]

[image: Firebase Dadtabase]

Comment: If the `TextView`s are in the form of a list, consider using `RecyclerView`. Or if it is in the form of a grid, consider using `GridView`

Comment: I'll just add the activity. The textviews need to be positioned as above..

Comment: The most efficient way is to store all of the `TextView` as single array of object, maybe `TextView[]` or `List<TextView>`. Then inside the `snapshot` loop, just call `TextView` from there one by one.

Comment: @koceeng I've put the Textviews in a single array object. Could you elaborate, how to match the names in my ArrayList to the textviews

Comment: That's for you to decide, is there any indicator or anything in data you saved in firebase that can be used to determine who is where?

Comment: yes, each child has an id and has to match a specific textview.

Comment: I've just added my an image of my database @koceeng

Answer (score 0):

You should place all the `TextView` and their desired ids into `HashMap`, like this:

```
// init object
HashMap<Integer, TexView> textViewMap = new HashMap<>();

... onCreate(...) {
    ....
    // put value inside
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_1);
    textViewMap.put(1, textView1);
    ...
}
```

Then when you get data from Firebase Database, you can use stored id you placed there to indicate which `TextView` the data belongs:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        // if you use custom Player object, replace following line
        Integer id = snapshot.child("id").getValue(Integer.class);
        String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);

        // then get the TextView and put text in it
        textViewMap.get(id).setText(name);
    }
    ...
}
```

That should do it. Hope this helps.